# Open in Explorer View Using SSL

Tags: 2013, ssl, open-with-explorer

In [a previous post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/94344/open-with-explorer-via-ssl-with-sni), I was exploring using the Open With Explorer button with SNI enabled, and we came to the likely conclusion that this is not a supported configuration. After researching that, I discovered that I couldn't even get Open With Explorer to work if SSL was enabled at all. With SSL disabled, explorer view and all other functions work fine. The web application was created with SSL enabled and there are no extended sites.

Clicking on the button in IE (tested with IE10 on Win7 with [IE hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2629108) and IE11 on Win8) produces the error message below:

```
\\servername@SSL\DavWWWRoot is not accessible. You might not have
permission to use this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if
you have access permissions.

A device attached to the system is not functioning
```

Testing the connection using the following command

```
Net Use z: \\servername@SSL\DavWWWRoot\Library
```

produces one of the following two errors, alternating on each attempt to attach.

```
System error 1790 has occurred.

The network logon failed.
________________________________

System error 59 has occurred.

An unexpected error has occurred.
```

Attempting to attach to the library using the Sync button (office 2013 installed) causes the OneDrive for Business application to spin trying to connect, but never completes; it tries without success until the groove.exe application is terminated. I am currently running a self signed cert for testing, however I do get a dialog to accept the cert which, coupled with the context of the error message, leads me to believe that the self signed cert is not the issue.

Please feel free to ask if more clarification is required and thank you for taking the time to help.

---

Environment: SharePoint 2013 onsite, SP1; Server 2012 RTM with all updates applied; Single SP server running all SP roles (no OWA installed)

Clients: Windows 7 Enterprise x64 with IE10, Windows 8.1 Enterprise x64 with IE11, both Office 2013.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK. This was actually a surprisingly straightforward answer and it's the direct result of a failed assumption, specifically that a non-trusted cert can be used.

When connecting, the system would show me the questionable certs that it identified with an OK/cancel box to, presumably, accept the unsatisfactory certificate. Following a hunch, I grabbed our PKI guy and got him to issue me a cert for the test site. Upon binding the cert to the IIS site, everything worked great.

Thanks to anyone who took the time to read this. I hope this can be of use to the next person coming along and trying to set up a test SP build with SSL!

Comment: Please mark your post as an answer.

Comment: I attempted to do so, but the system told me I must wait 2 days to mark my post as an answer. Is there something I should do to accelerate the process?