# Mapping SharePoint (using https) on-premis as a network drive

Tags: sharepoint-server

Does anyone know how to map SharePoint 2013 on premis (using https, not http) as a network drive ?

Comment: process is same for http and https. Just make sure you site is in trusted list

Comment: @Atish I have completed the process for http - I could map as a network drive and open in explorer for http case in both SharePoint server machine and a remote machine. Also, I could also map SharePoint online instance to a network drive. But when i changed the bindings for SharePoint on-premis to only https. I cannot open in explorer anymore. Also network drive on my remote machine I mapped earlier is no longer available.

Comment: Seems network issue. Try from another pc or domain pc

Comment: also check the issues from here https://nikpatel.net/2014/12/23/mapping-network-drive-for-office-365-and-sharepoint-online/

Comment: If you map a network drive using HTTP, then switch the site to HTTPS, your former network mapped drive will no longer function. It is like you want to access the site via the same HTTP-based URL as earlier.

Answer (score 1):

To map your HTTPS-based site to a network drive, yopu should use the format:

```
\\websitename\@ssl@port#\DavWWWRoot
```

like

```
\\www.yourwebsite.com\@ssl@443\DavWWWRoot
```

See the detailed description [here](http://www.howtonetworking.com/msapps/sharepoint12.htm) and a few troubleshooting tips [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/mapping-sharepoint-document-libraries-without-getting-nik-d-agostino?forceNoSplash=true).

Comment: I think I have created a self signed certificate which is a problem. I was able to open with  Explorer before, when I was using HTTP. After that I created a self signed certificate which is not trusted by the browser and edited the bindings to use only https. Maybe this is the problem

Comment: Of course you should have a certificate your operating system trusts.

Comment: You also have to note that you do not enable "Server Name Indication" (SNI) in your IIS-Bindings. This will break WebDAV on older Windows-Clients (http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/94344/open-with-explorer-via-ssl-with-sni).